# Drupal Commerce order completes but reverts from pending to billing

Tags: commerce

We are having issues where a Commerce Order will complete checkout, but once marked Paid in Full and set as Pending, it bounces back to Billing and Shipping (Shipping checkout page, name changed.)

Edit: We are using Authorize.net, no IPN.

[image: Customer submits payment, gets pushed to Checkout: Complete, or sent to pending. Then for some reason it bumps back to Checkout: Billing & Shipping which resets the order's shipping.]

Our checkout settings:

- Checkout

  - Shopping cart contents
  - Coupons
  - Account Information
- Billing and Shipping (default Shipping page, name changed)

  - Billing information
  - Shipping information
  - Shipping Service
- Billing (empty, moved into previous page)
- Review and Payment

  - Review
  - Payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually had to do with Commerce Order entity revisions and Commerce Shipping. During checkout AJAX shipping rate calls were not properly checking form state, causing the order revision ID to set back after checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the order processing rules.

Look into whether your payment gateway is firing an IPN / notification which changes the order. If some orders process in a different order (eg some browsers varies in speed and fires checkout rules in a different order to the others) then you can see this sort of inconsistent behaviour.

Your checkout rules can permit EITHER the IPN or customer redirect to provide checkout notification - this can avoid showing some customers "we're awaiting confirmation from payment gateway". Just check order status and don't update an order which is already completed.

Your gateway may refer to IPN under another name. IPN requests can be discerned by the differing origin IP and authentication (if purchase is from a logged in user, but the above image is an anonymous purchase so not discernible there).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention its Authorize.net and no IPN. Updated question